# Maximum order of element of finite general linear group

Tags: matrices, group-theory, finite-groups

The question may have been appeared, but I didn't find here.

> In matrix group ${\rm GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$, the largest order of any element is *equal to* $q^n-1$.

It is easy to show existence of element of order $q^n-1$ (by embedding $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}^*$ in this group).

On the other hand, if $A\in {\rm GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ is of order $k$, then $A^k=I$, so minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $x^k-1$. I was unable to move to prove that $k\le q^n-1$. How to proceed? Any hint?

Comment: It is proves as Corollary 2 of [this paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82438978.pdf). I doubt whether there is any easier way to prove it.

Comment: I am interested in this question.  I do not see the "easy" embedding of $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}^*$ into $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$.  How does the structure of $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}^*$ allow us to embed into this matrix group with entries in the subfield $\mathbb{F}_q$? @DerekHolt

Comment: @Randall ${\mathbb F}_{q^n}$ has the structure of a vector space of dimension $n$ over ${\mathbb F}_q$. Multiplication by a primitive element of ${\mathbb F}_{q^n}^*$ defines a linear map of order $q^n-1$ of this space, and corresponds to an element of order $q^n-1$ of ${\rm GL}(n,q)$, which acts regularly on nonzero vectors. Such elements are called *Singer cycles* (which you could search for).

Comment: @DerekHolt  Got it/makes complete sense.  Thanks.

Comment: But you need to search for something like "singer cycle mathematics", or you will get a lot of unwanted information about bikes!

Comment: @DerekHolt ha yes!  I just figured that out.

Comment: It turns out that George Singer was mayor of Coventry (which is where I live) from 1891 - 1894, and dies in Coventry - very interesting but irrelevant, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be your element of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$.  Consider the subring generated by $A$ inside the ring of all $n \times n$ matrices.  By the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, this is a vector space of dimension **at most** $n$ since $A$ satifies the degree $n$ polynomial identity $\det(xI-A)=0$.  Since this is of dimension at most $n$ over the field $\mathbb{F}_q$, this subring consists of at most $q^n$ elements.  Removing $0$ from consideration, it consists of at most $q^n-1$ non-zero elements. Hence the order of $A$ as an element of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ is bounded by $q^n-1$.

Comment: That's certainly a lot easier than the proof in the paper I linked to, but of course that was also handling maximal element orders in related groups like ${\rm SL}(n,q)$.

Comment: Yes, it all seems much harder in $\operatorname{SL}(n,q)$.